# Editing custom.css to make responsive version

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, web-developer-toolbar

I am supposed to make responsive stylesheet for a website but it is so messed up that they can not make a working copy for me to edit. For that reason I thought of editing

```
Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\custom.css
```

while browsing their website, adding breakpoints and later save it and add it to their header.
It works but the problem is that this stylesheet is not a priority so every rule needs to have !important. 
Is there a better way?
If I could inject link to css after all other stylesheets it would be used as priority. What is your workflow? How would you do this? Ideas?

Comment: Why can they not give you a copy of the CSS file? Can you not just view the file in your web browser and save a copy?
I assume you are talking about editing custom.css while you are working on making it responsive. Then you can just use inspect element and adjust the styles in Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: The website is wordpress and has 10 css files which I can save but don't want to edit, just to make another css for responsive version with media queries and mave it at the bottom of list of css-es.

Comment: Are you asking how to add the CSS to the WordPress site, or how to work on it to develop the responsive stylesheet?

Comment: @BryanGentry just interested in workflow of modifying Chrome's \User StyleSheets\custom.css for live website

Comment: OK, I understand your question better now. Thank you for clarifying. I just posted an answer with my recommendation, which is to go a different route rather than editing and trying to inject this Chrome stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than edit and try injecting this Chrome stylesheet, I would recommend the following:

1. Create a blank CSS file Add this CSS file to the header of the site
   as the last CSS file loaded
2. While viewing this site, open Chrome developer tools and open that css file in the "sources" pane.
3. Edit the file here, and copy, paste, and save the changes periodically.

All your edits to this file will take priority over other stylesheets, so no need to make everything !important.